# using gridview width while specifying child width in getView

Tags: android, gridview

I am using a custom adapter for my grid view which just return an image view of width 1/3 the size of its parent the app is rendering all the view except at position 0 I think its because parent width and height is 0 while rendering first view how can I get parentwidth for the first view i.e view at position 0

here is my getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) (parent
                .getMeasuredWidth() / 3f),
                (int) (parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 3f)));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    System.out.println(ids[position].intValue());
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getContext().getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_white));
    } else {
        imageView.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.shadow_white));
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(ids[position].intValue());
    System.out.println("getView" + imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

and this is my grid view declaration in xml

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/category_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
```